# how to implement url rewriting in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

how to implement url rewriting in classic ASP

thanks,
Aaryan

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090553/is-it-possible-to-do-friendly-url-url-rewriting-in-classic-asp

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=asp+url+rewrite+-.net)

Answer (score 2):

If it is not IIS7 then you should use ISAPI (for best results):

http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/IIRF.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is best practice, but I've hacked it together long ago just using a custom 404 asp page and the server variables.

Comment: Thats all we do, works a treat and you have complete control.

Answer (score 1):

I don't suppose you're using IIS7?  You can use the [IIS7 Url Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/extensions/URLRewrite)...