# SEO friendly URL in Classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic, seo

I have website developed in [classic ASP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages). The URL is not [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) friendly at present.

Please suggest how I can make the SEO friendly URL for my website in ASP.

Is there any supporting functions which can help in creating SEO friendly URL in ASP?

URL for product Information page like this :
http://www.yourdomain.com/store/template/template2/Default.asp?mainpage=product_info&P_ID=18047

---

Thanks for your help.

I have read the documentation and Installed the IIRF properly.Now i have few queries.I tried few sample with redirection and they are wrking.I put the clean URL in address bar and result shows data from the original URL.

My Problems: I am still bit confused abt the rewrite and redirect.I don't expect you to teach and guide me for the same.Please pardon me if i write confusing sometime.Please feel free to guide me if i am wrong in approach for SEO friendly URL's.

My Goal is to create SEO friendly URL's for my shopping cart.what I want when page gets parsed in browser it should show the Parsed links as SEO friendly not the original one.

As in my sample when i type  URL in address bar it didn't gets changed to clean URL. When i type the clean URL in address bar it shows the data from original URL.

In my shopping cart there are lot of Hyperlinks to other pages.They are also in Dynamic in nature not the static one.How can i set those static hyperlinks to clean URL using IIRF without making substantial changes in my cart.

regards,
Sunny

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090553/is-it-possible-to-do-friendly-url-url-rewriting-in-classic-asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have used isapi rewrite before and it works very well, very configurable per site etc

http://www.isapirewrite.com/

Answer (score 4):

Configure IIS to do URL Rewriting. Microsoft has an addon for IIS7 (Vista, Server 2008), but you can install [IIRF](http://www.codeplex.com/IIRF) (open source) in IIS5.1 (XP) and IIS6 (Server 2003).

Let all incoming requests or any path starting with `/media/` (or pick your own) go through un-rewritten. Only put static files in there such as CSS/JavaScript/images.

Rewrite all incoming request URLS from, e.g., `/foo/bar?abc=xyz` to `/index.asp/foo/bar?abc=xyz`. The rewriting is all *internal to IIS* so the end-user does *not* see any URL rewriting.

Within `index.asp`, you can access the original incoming URL `/foo/bar` via

```
<%= Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME") %>
<%= Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO") %>
<%= Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING") %>
```

yielding

```
/index.asp
/foo/bar
abc=xyz
```

Comment: Assuming he's running on IIS7 which does not have ASP installed as default. More than likely its an old IIS6 (or even 5) install?

Comment: @justice
we have successfully installed IIRF.Now we have written the following rewrite rule, but its not working.Kindly suggest :

existing url: http://domain.com/scripts/page.asp?mid=2&pageid=5
desired ur: http://domain.com/scripts/page/2/5/

-------------
RewriteEngine ON
StatusUrl /iirfStatus
RewriteLog C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\iirf
RewriteLogLevel 3
# When someone surfs to the default page, they get  
RewriteRule ^/$                      /scripts/default.asp
# Rewrite content links for SEO
RewriteRule ^/scripts/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/  /scripts/page.asp?mid=$1&pageid=$2

Comment: Try changing it to `RewriteRule ^/scripts/page/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /scripts/page.asp?mid=$1&pageid=$2`