# Classic ASP url rewrite module

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to do friendly url (url rewriting) in classic asp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090553/is-it-possible-to-do-friendly-url-url-rewriting-in-classic-asp)

Is it possible to configure url rewriting in IIS7 for a classic asp site?
I've installed url rewrite module for IIS.
I've followed the instructions to set up Inbound and Outbound rules.

The original url is http://mydomain.com/Products.asp?Param=9319&ig_id=31457&title=Electric

When I try my new url something like http://mydomain.com/Products/9319/31457/Electric I get the following error

HTTP Error 404.2 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the ISAPI and CGI Restriction list settings on the Web server.

I have tried exactly the same approach with a .NET test site and everything worked fine.  Any help would be appreciated.
Please remember that is this a classic ASP site not .NET

I've followed what is in the links provided below will still no joy.  I've tried to write a custom 404 page and set this as the 404 page in IIS, but the 404 page doesn't seem to be getting called.
Thanks

Comment: It seems it's possible, when you look at the answer for this old SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090553/is-it-possible-to-do-friendly-url-url-rewriting-in-classic-asp

Comment: Did you already try to edit the IIS7 restriction list for the asp.dll ? Details can be found here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754974(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Yes AardVark71 I've followed the instructions in your second post to no avail.  I am looking at the first link thank you for this