# Single Page ASP application and Routing

Tags: asp-classic, routes

I thought this would be very simple but it's proved difficult to find the information I'm looking for online... I have a single page website using ASP and I want to use query strings but I don't want to have to put Default.asp in the URL. So at the moment the URL would be something like:

`http://localhost/default.asp?id=4`

But I'd like something like:

`http://localhost/watch?id=4`

I'm not using Visual Studio so was hoping to be able to do this with a simple text editor. I'm not that familiar with ASP either so this I'm very much a newbie with these concepts.

Comment: Check this discussion:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090553/is-it-possible-to-do-friendly-url-url-rewriting-in-classic-asp

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.

**1: Use URLRewrite extension from Microsoft that can be found [here](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)**

You can set-up an inbound rule for the pattern: `watch` using wildcards, and add conditions that disable the rule when a file or directory actually exists. (URL Rewrite sets this by default), then create your action to point to `default.asp` and check the `Append query string` box.  Then it will route all `/watch` url's to your `default.asp` page and will allow your script to read all querystrings as it does normally.

**2: Use a custom 404 error page:**

Point your error 404 page to the default.asp page in IIS, but you will need to use `Request.ServerVariables("Querystring")` to parse out the actual URL requested, since the 404 error page is not able to get your querystring by using `Request.Querystring` as you will be able to do in option 1.  You will have to create your own url reading system, since the data returned as the querystring would be something like `?404;http://www.domain.com/watch?id=12312`, instead of `?id=12312` like it would in option 1.

Personally I would use the 1st option, even though it requires to install the extension, it's more flexible and doesn't fill up the logs with 2 seperate requests like option 2 does, and its just more transparent to your script rather than creating your own url reading system as you would have to using option 2.